# pkpass not downloading on physical iOS device

Tags: ios, apple-wallet, pkpass

**Background:** I'm learning Apple Wallet by creating a barebones sample app and am trying to automatically update a pass. In order to do so, I understand I need to run a web server that sends push notifications to the device when it's time for the pass to update. I'm using [Apple's sample code](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/iOS/Wallet_Support_Materials/WalletCompanionFiles.zip) and running their Ruby webserver via localhost. It correctly generates a .pkpass file, which I can add to Apple Wallet in the simulator by visiting the localhost site or by dragging in the .pkpass file.

**Problem:** This process doesn't work on my physical iPhone. When I go to the localhost on my iPhone, it shows a 200 response code but comes with the popup "Safari cannot download this file." Even if I try just emailing the generated .pkpass file to myself, it won't open in Wallet.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may be wondering, I got it to work by changing the web host to https. Then I ran into another problem getting automatic updates to work, solved here: [How to allow HTTP webServiceURL in apple wallet's pass.json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72902081/how-to-allow-http-webserviceurl-in-apple-wallets-pass-json-file)