# How to allow HTTP webServiceURL in apple wallet's pass.json file

Tags: apple-wallet

I'm creating a web service for automatic updates to a pass, just for testing purposes. According to [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/walletpasses/adding_a_web_service_to_update_passes): "Your web service must use an HTTPS connection for production, but you can use an HTTP connection during testing." However, it seems that I can't actually use HTTP for testing because if I put webServiceURL in pass.json as http, the pkpass file cannot open. Is there a way to force allow an HTTP webServiceURL in pass.json?

*Note: if I change my web service to https with an SSL certificate, the pass downloads, but I don't get any post requests from Apple's service to my endpoint to register the pass. I could be doing this wrong but I'm not familiar enough with the https process (or how apple actually calls my endpoint) to know how to fix it. I can post more details about this if that would be a better approach.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by using [ngrok](https://gist.github.com/wosephjeber/aa174fb851dfe87e644e). I run the localhost, then run ngrok at the same port, and it provides an https url that works with Apple. Only downside is you need to restart ngrok with a new link every 2hrs, and don't forget to update the pass.json file webServiceURL.